# SQL Query to show Property data where user table id matches with property table user_id

Tags: mysql, join

im trying to select records of property table where it should show all fields of property table when property table's user_id matches with user table's user_id.

Im trying this query but it shows all records from both table with duplicate entries of same data.

```
SELECT * FROM `property` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `property`.`user_id`=16;
```

[Here is the Screenshot of duplicate records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6gbK.png)

Can anyone please help me correct my query?

Comment: The `ON` clause should contain the relationship between `property` and `users`.

Comment: `ON property.user_id = user.user_id`

Comment: ON clause is working fine which you mentioned but when i enter actual users.user_id i.e, 16, it gives duplicate records of same id

Comment: You're getting cross product with all the users, since you don't have `users.user_id = 16`

Comment: You might want to change `*` to `property.*` as well, in order to not receive all fields from both tables.

Comment: i have user_id = 16, it's showing that user_id record twich but in fact it has only one record, also cross product as you said is also showing, any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: @GuidoFaecke thanks man now im getting records from property table but duplicate entries are still there, i have attached Screenshot in my question to show the problem

Comment: As @Barmar mentioned, change your `ON` clause to `ON property.user_id = user.user_id` and MAYBE change `users.user_id = 16` into a `where` clause.

Comment: Thank you so much, it took me some time to figure out the problem i was missing Where clause, co-incidentally i just figured it out and you gave solution at same time.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution with help of people in comments section and myself :D

```
SELECT `property`.* 
FROM `property` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `property`.`user_id`=`users`.`user_id` 
WHERE `property`.`user_id`=16;
```